# Power series and exponential excercise

Tags: complex-analysis

The power series $f(z):= \sum_{\nu \geq 0}a_{\nu}z^{\nu}$ converges in a disc $B$ centered at $0$. For every $z\in B$ such that $2z$ is also in $B$, $f$ satisfies $f(2z) = (f(z))^{2}$. Show that if $f(0)\neq 0$, then $f(z)=\mathrm{exp} bz$, with $b:=f'(0)=a_{1}.$

*I'm completely lost with this problem. Could someone give me a hint?*

Comment: I'm also lost. Shouldn't the series for $f(z)$ start with $\nu=0$ in order that $f(0)\neq 0$?

Comment: yep I'm sorry that's a typo. I'll fix it immediatly.

Comment: I think the course of action would be to prove that the power series is holomorphic and then calculate it's derivatives to see if it satisties f' = f.  But I'm kind of confused with the propperties of power series. It would be great if someone could give me some steps to follow and then I can fill the gaps as to how to use power series.

Comment: @Chu: I think it is obvious that the power series is holomorphic (inside the convergence radius), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions. If it is not obvious, what do you already know about holomorphic functions?

Comment: In principle, you can plug in the power series into $f(2z) = (f(z))^2$ and compare coefficients order by order in $z$.

Comment: So I differentiate inside the disc determined by the convergence radius and plug into $f(2z)=(f(z))^{2}$ right?

Comment: @Chu: now you lost me. What you want to differentiate? What you want to plug into $f(2z)=(f(z))^{2}$? As I see it you can plug the expression for $f(z)$ into $f(2z)=(f(z))^{2}$ and then compare term by term in $z$. Alternatively (and easier), because $f(0) \neq 0$, $g(z)=\log f(z)$ is holomorphic in a region around $0$, so you can arrive at an equation for $g$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you can and can't do with power series. Let me do the computations the way you suggest :)

Comment: @Chu: because the function is holomorphic, you can differentiate as often as you want. If you have a power series then the $\nu$-th term is the $\nu$-th derivative evaluated at $z=0$. If two holomorphic functions are equal then their power series is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can plug in $z = 0$ to get that $a_0 = 1$. Since $\log(1 + z)$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$, the composition $\log(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n) = \log(f(z))$ will also be analytic on some disk $D$ centered at $z = 0$. Let $g(z) = \log(f(z))$. Your conditions say that $g(2z) = 2g(z)$ now. Look at the power series of $g(z)$ to show that this equation forces $g(z)$ to be of the form $cz$, and you have enough info to figure out what $c$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take the logarithm of your equation and arrive at an equation for $g(z) = \log f(z)$.